# Repeater not working fine when passed a dataprovider (array) having a single element

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I am using a Repeater in an Accordian which does not appear to see a single element in userArray. If I add another entry to userArray then the Repeater works fine.

Thoughts??

```
    private function currUsersServiceHandler(event:ResultEvent):void{

                    if (event.result.currentUsers != null)
                    {
                        if (event.result.currentUsers.user is ArrayCollection) // if more than one elements are present
                        {
                            usersArray = event.result.currentUsers.user;
                        } 
                        else if (event.result.currentUsers is ObjectProxy)
                        { //FIXIT usersArray populate by following line has some issue
                            usersArray = new ArrayCollection(ArrayUtil.toArray(event.result.currentUsers));
                        }
                    }
                }

        <mx:HTTPService id="currUsersService" url="currUsers.xml" result="currUsersServiceHandler(event)"/>

<mx:Accordion includeIn="UserList" x="10" y="10" width="554" height="242" >
        <mx:Repeater id="rep" dataProvider="{usersArray}">
            <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" label="{rep.currentItem.firstName}" >
                    <mx:HBox>
                        <s:Label text="{rep.currentItem.firstName}"/>
                        <s:Label text="{rep.currentItem.lastName}"/>
                      <mx:/HBox>
            </mx:Canvas>
        </mx:Repeater>  
</mx:Accordian>
```

Edit:

There is another thing I have just noticed i.e. that the accordian does show a single tab (when Array has a single element) but it's not labeled with the first name which I am setting. If I enter another user, two tabs appear and both are labeled with names I am setting. The first tab appears labeled too then.

Comment: No worries. Does your repeater work if you remove it from the Accordion tags?

Comment: Repeater needs a container, right? So I need to have to have Accordian (the container). If I remove the Accordian tags then I get following error: Repeaters requires a Halo container based parent

Comment: Yep, it does. Have you tried a `VBox`?

Comment: Just did. Same problem. Works fine if the array has two elements (i.e shows the first one then too).

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to me that this would not work with 1 item in the dataProvider, but would work with two.

That said, tThis approach strikes me as convoluted and I tend to stay away from using repeaters at all.  I would suggest a different approach.

First create a component to display your data.  You can reuse you're existing code.  Conceptually something like this:

```
        <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%"  >
<mx:Script><[[ 
 public var user : Object;
]]></mx:Script>
                <mx:HBox>
                    <s:Label text="{user.firstName}"/>
                    <s:Label text="{user.lastName}"/>
                  <mx:/HBox>
        </mx:Canvas>
```

Then in your original component create the new instance of the component in ActionScript:

```
for each(var myUserObject : Object in usersArray){
  var newUserDisplayObject : UserDisplayObject = new UserDisplayObject();
  newUserDisplayObject.user = myUserObject;
  newUserDisplayObject.label = myUserObject.firstName
  accordian.addChild(newUserDisplayObject);
}
```

Comment: @Flextras, Adobe has also posted an example using a Repeater in an Accordion so it *should* be possible. http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_E4X_Accordion_Repeater-1488.html Your example is still sound though. :)